# Error: Cannot use typeid with -fno-rtti

Tags: c++, objective-c, xcode, gcc, compilation

I´m getting this "Cannot use typeid with -fno-rtti" when I´m trying to compile my project, I´m using an opencv framework.
I googled the problem but, it seems the errors I found in internet does not have relation with my problem.
I don´t know if the problem is related with the includes, the code or the compiler.

Xcode is giving me the error a lot of times, but the first error is here:

```
virtual const std::type_info& type() { return typeid(T); }
```

Comment: for Android NDK: cppFlags += "-frtti"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's telling you the error right in the message: if you use the `no-rtti` flag on the compiler, then `typeid` is not going to be available. Just enable RTTI; it's part of C++ after all.

Answer (score 3):

RTTI stands for Run Time Type Information, and `typeid` is an RTTI-feature. So turning off RTTI (`-fno-rtti`) also disables features like `typeid`.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RTTI for more information about RTTI in C++.